# Using Python typing's TypeVar for generically typed returns with bound

Tags: python, mypy

When trying to use typing's TypeVar to enable the use of generics with return types, I'm encountering a mypy error whereby the `bound` argument isn't accounted for when comparing the types of a dictionary and the expected return type of a function.

Below is an example of the situation I am facing:

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Type, TypeVar


class Bird:
    def call(self):
        print(self.sound)


class Chicken(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "bok bok"


class Owl(Bird):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "hoot hoot"


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Bird)


class Instantiator:
    def __init__(self, birds: List[Type[Bird]]):
        self._bird_map: Dict[Type[Bird], Bird] = {}
        for bird in birds:
            self._bird_map[bird] = bird()

    def get_bird(self, bird_type: Type[T]) -> T:
        return self._bird_map[bird_type]
```

Running a mypy validator will show: `temp.py:29: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Bird", expected "T")`

The `Instantiator` is used as a sort of 'tracker' for instantiating one of each bird type. When trying to retrieve the instantiated object based on a class type, this is why the use of generics is required as otherwise later typed fields will complain about using the `Bird` class rather than one of `Chicken` or `Owl`.

Am I incorrectly using `TypeVar` here? Is there a different way to approach the structure? Is this an oversight in mypy?

Comment: FWIW, `i = Instantiator([Bird, Owl, Chicken]); b = i.get_bird(Owl); b.call()` causes no errors in Pycharm, and it correctly identifies `b` as an `Owl`.

Comment: Your `get_bird` is also fairly close to `make_new_user` in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Comment: Yep, thank you @Carcigenicate, everything still works and everything external picks up on the typing correctly. It's just the dictionary types vs the return type of the `get_bird` function I see errors about. I assume PyCharm would still hint at that error if using mypy checks?

Comment: Note that both ``list`` and ``dict`` are *invariant* due to mutability. A ``Dict[..., Bird]`` contains *only* ``Bird``s not subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have defined a dict containing only base class objects `Bird`, but in the function `get_bird` you are trying to return an object of type of the base class, while an object of a derived class may be expected. `Mypy` will not make `Base -> Derived` cast.

You can make `__init__` also a generic function.

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Bird)

class Instantiator():
    def __init__(self, birds: List[Type[T]]):
        self._bird_map: Dict[Type[T], T] = {}
        for bird in birds:
            self._bird_map[bird] = bird()

    def get_bird(self, bird_type: Type[T]) -> T:
        return self._bird_map[bird_type]
```

Or use explicitly `cast`:

```
class Instantiator:
    def __init__(self, birds: List[Type[Bird]]):
        self._bird_map: Dict[Type[Bird], Bird] = {}
        for bird in birds:
            self._bird_map[bird] = bird()

    def get_bird(self, bird_type: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cast(T, self._bird_map[bird_type])
```

Comment: So if I wanted to create a method `get_birds()` which returned to me a mapping of the class to an instantiated class, I thought `def get_birds(self) -> Dict[Type[T], T]:` would give me an error based on the unknown generic type but because that's globally declared it's fine? And, something like `b: Dict[Type[Bird], Bird] = instantiator.get_birds()` would give no incompatible type errors?